# HTML table with second title halfway through column?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is it possible to make a *single* table in html like the following? I realize one could make it two separate tables, but I don’t want to do that because I want the tables to line up perfectly (one directly underneath another.)

Is the below possible?

```
SINGLE TABLE:
           Title 1
————————————————————————————————
|       |                      |
|       |                      |
|       |                      |
|       |                      |
|       |                      |
————————————————————————————————
           Title 2
————————————————————————————————
|       |                      |
|       |                      |
|       |                      |
|       |                      |
|       |                      |
————————————————————————————————
```

Comment: This is not a service site code

Comment: @dippas lol you answer first  and then delete and comment XD

Comment: I saw my mistake, so I corrected  it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick..

```
In your CSS add ..
th {
  text-align: center;
  background: pink;
}
```

in your HTML add.

```
<table>
       <tr>
     <!----><th colspan="2">title 1</th>
       </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row 1.1</td>
            <td>row 1.2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row 2.1</td>
            <td>row 2.2</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
     <!----><th colspan="2">title 2</th>
       </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row 3.1</td>
            <td>row 3.2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row 4.1</td>
            <td >row 4.2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Just add `<th></th>` where you want the Title Row..

**EDIT**
Added  tags to table header. Plus the CSS for centering as @Paulie_D suggested.

Comment: `th` must have a `tr` parent and you haven't mentioned the width issue. Nice option though. - https://jsfiddle.net/2tny25pg/

Answer (score 1):

You can generate html tables here: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables
I was able to do something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-yw4l"></th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l"></th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```